# ROS network bandwidth requirements

Tags: turtlebot, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, bandwidth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a turtlebot system with the laptop and workstation both running Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Fuerte.

My question is what is the necessary network connection speed between the two laptops in order for ROS to run reliably. I can currently get a MAXIMUM speed of .25 mbits/sec. (the connection is achieved through a SLIP connection of two Xbee-Pro-PKG modems). Is this connection speed going to be fast enough once I add more turtlebots to my system? (i.e. the turtlebots will need to communicate across the Xbees to coordinate their efforts, so will this connection allow that communication to happen reliably?)

Thanks in advance for your input.

EDIT:
I have only just begun working with ROS so my knowledge is limited, but ONE of my goals is to eventually have a team of 5 or so turtlebots working together to build a SLAM map of a large area to create one coherent map of said area. My guess is that the slow connection would make a task such as this difficult... would you agree?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51931/ros-network-bandwidth-requirements/) by [JillTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/3786/jillturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on what you want to do/send.

ROS puts some slight overhead on the messages, but mainly it's the data you are transferring. If it is only low-rate coordination commands that should be OK. If you want to transfer 3D point clouds at 30Hz your speed won't be enough.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2